Powershell split data from column into multiple column
I have issue with one of my CSV which is exported from 3rd part tool vendor.
Data looks like below
FQDN        Days
device_1    Fri 20:00-23:59; Sat 00:00-23:59; Sun 00:00-23:59, Mon 00:00-07:00
device_2    Fri 20:00-23:59; Sat 00:00-23:59; Sun 00:00-23:59, Mon 00:00-07:00
device_3    Fri 20:00-23:59; Sat 00:00-23:59; Sun 00:00-23:59, Mon 00:00-07:00
device_4    Fri 22:00-23:59; Sat 00:00-23:59; Sun 00:00-23:59, Mon 00:00-07:00
device_5    Mon 00:00-:08:45, 23:00-23:59;  Tue 00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59;  Wed 00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59;  Thu 00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59;  Fri 00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59;  Sat Fri 00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59;  Sun Fri 00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59;
device_6    Mon 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Tue 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Wed 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Thu 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Fri 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Sat 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Sun 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59;
device_7    Mon 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Tue 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Wed 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Thu 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Fri 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Sat 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Sun 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59;
device_8    Mon 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Tue 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Wed 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Thu 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Fri 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Sat 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59; Sun 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59;

I need to convert this file using PowerShell to have time for specific day in separate column with name of day. Moreover I see that data in initial "Days" columns is not in regular week day order and it need to be assigned into correct column.
looks like below
FQDN        Mon                      Tue                   Wed             Thu  Fri Sat Sun
device_1    00:00-07:00                                                         20:00-23:59 00:00-23:59 00:00-23:59
device_2    00:00-07:00                                                         20:00-23:59 00:00-23:59 00:00-23:59
device_3    00:00-07:00                                                         20:00-23:59 00:00-23:59 00:00-23:59
device_4    00:00-07:00                                                         20:00-23:59 00:00-23:59 00:00-23:59
device_5    00:00-:08:45, 23:00-23:59   00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59    00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59    00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59    00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59    00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59    00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59
device_6    00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59     00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59    00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59   00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59    00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59    00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59    00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59
device_7    00:00-:08:45, 23:00-23:59   00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59    00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59    00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59    00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59    00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59    00:00-08:45, 23:00-23:59
device_8    00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59     00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59    00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59   00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59    00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59    00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59    00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59

Thank you for support

What did you try? Which problem are you facing? How many rows does your file contain?

rather lack of knowledge or basic knowledge how to do it

Quick thoughts: 1st read the CSV as it is to extract the 2 columns (FQDN and Days). Then, loop over the rows. Parse the Days values to extract the nested values, and reemit a new PSCustomObject with the desired structure. Finally export the data as CSV.

Try following.
$filename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$data = Get-Content -Path $filename | Select-Object -Skip 1 
$table = [System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]::new()

foreach ($line in $data) {
   $fqdn = $line.substring(0,11).Trim()
   $days = $line.substring(11).split(@(';',','))
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   foreach ($day in $days) {

      if($day.Length -ge 4) {
         $day -match '^(?<days>[^\d]*)(?<hours>.*)' | Out-Null
         $dayOfWeek = $Matches.days.trim()

         if($dayOfWeek.Length -gt 0) { 
            $hours = $Matches.hours.trim()
            $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $dayOfWeek -NotePropertyValue $hours
            $previousDayOfWeek = $dayOfWeek
         }
         else {
            $newRow.$previousDayOfWeek += $day
         }
      }
   }
   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}

$table | Format-List

Here is results
Fri : 20:00-23:59
Sat : 00:00-23:59
Sun : 00:00-23:59
Mon : 00:00-07:00

Fri : 20:00-23:59
Sat : 00:00-23:59
Sun : 00:00-23:59
Mon : 00:00-07:00

Fri : 20:00-23:59
Sat : 00:00-23:59
Sun : 00:00-23:59
Mon : 00:00-07:00

Fri : 22:00-23:59
Sat : 00:00-23:59
Sun : 00:00-23:59
Mon : 00:00-07:00

Mon     : 00:00-:08:45 23:00-23:59
Tue     : 00:00-08:45 23:00-23:59
Wed     : 00:00-08:45 23:00-23:59
Thu     : 00:00-08:45 23:00-23:59
Fri     : 00:00-08:45 23:00-23:59
Sat Fri : 00:00-08:45 23:00-23:59
Sun Fri : 00:00-08:45 23:00-23:59

Mon : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Tue : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Wed : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Thu : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Fri : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Sat : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Sun : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59

Mon : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Tue : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Wed : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Thu : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Fri : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Sat : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Sun : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59

Mon : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Tue : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Wed : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Thu : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Fri : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Sat : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59
Sun : 00:00-00:00 23:45-23:59


I am getting such error `Exception setting "Sun": "The property 'Sun' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can
be set."
At D:\BRestAPI\APIBP2\APIBP2.ps1:58 char:13


        $newRow.$previousDayOfWeek += $day



        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting`




Are you using same data that was posted?  I was getting same error with my code and modified code to fix issue. The error was occurring because you used both comma and semicolons to separate the fields.  So data like Mon 00:00-00:00, 23:45-23:59 I had to combine add the 23:45-23:59 to the previous field "Mon" and "Mon" did not exist.  The REGEX is splitting the DAY : HOUR into two parts based on finding the first digit.  When there is no Day of Week  I take the hours and add to the previous field.  So code expects SUN HH:mm - HH:mm, HH:mm - HH:mm and instead is seeing something else.
